# DateTime difference in ticks does not match

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
var a = (DateTime.Now.Subtract(DateTime.Now.AddTicks(8))).Ticks;
var b = (DateTime.Now - DateTime.Now.AddTicks(8)).Ticks;
```

When I check the values I see that:

```
a = -78
b = -20
```

How come? Shouldn't both be -8?

Comment: Not unless you're on a real-time operating system.

Comment: Does it work as expected if you capture the DateTime.Now in a variable?

Comment: `Now` is not a static value, change `Now` to `Today` and you will get your desired results. (unless you run at midnight)

Comment: @Amy Even if you *are* on a real time operating system it won't guarentee that all operations take the same amount of time, as would be required for this to be true.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are depending on the system to do everything at the same time, which it cannot. Each time you get `DateTime.Now`, it has a different value.

A quick experiment reveals that capturing the value of `DateTime.Now` in the beginning, and then performing operations on that:

```
var d = DateTime.Now;
var a = (d.Subtract(d.AddTicks(8))).Ticks;
var b = (d - d.AddTicks(8)).Ticks;
```

Yields the result you were expecting. `a` and `b` have the same value, `-8`.

Comment: you beat me to this answer by 45 seconds

Comment: @P.Roe It pays off to be the [Fastest Gun in the West](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem)

Comment: @L.B Exactly. OP was baffled because in their case it didn't. The problem wasn't with the math, it was because they didn't realize one operand was constantly changing.

Answer (score 1):

Those lines of code take time to execute. It's never good to use `Now` more than once in single method or operation. Or `Today`, for that matter.