# DateTime.Now Assign 2 Variables From 1 Call

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, xamarin, xamarin.forms

EDIT*{ Original title = "DateTime.Now different when setting 2 variables".

What I want to do is assign one variable, using the date time of another which gets its value set from DateTime.Now

}

This question in essence is similar to this ["DateTime difference in ticks does not match"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46162349/datetime-difference-in-ticks-does-not-match/46162428).

Basically I have a form and the user can select a date & a time, I check if the user has edited the form when the close button is pressed. If they have edited the form a popup will show asking the user if they wish to abandon changes.

When I init the form (for creation) I run this code in a method called `InitEvent()`:

```
var startDate = DateTime.Now;
var endDate = startDate.AddHours(1);
var startTime = startDate.TimeOfDay;
var endTime = endDate.TimeOfDay;

_eventStartDate = startDate;
_eventEndDate = endDate;
_eventStartTime = startTime;
_eventEndTime = endTime;

_uneditedEvent = new EventItem()
{
    StartDateTime = _eventStartDate,
    EndDateTime = _eventEndDate,
};
```

Before the form is dismissed I run some code to check for unsaved changes:

```
if (_uneditedEvent.Type != _eventItem.Type || 
    _uneditedEvent.CustomerCode != _eventItem.CustomerCode || 
    _uneditedEvent.ProjectCode != _eventItem.ProjectCode || 
    _uneditedEvent.StartDateTime != _eventItem.StartDateTime || 
    _uneditedEvent.EndDateTime != _eventItem.EndDateTime || 
    _uneditedEvent.Notes != _eventItem.Notes)
{
    var action = await _pageDialogue.DisplayAlertAsync("Unsaved Changes", "Do you want to abandon this event?", "Yes", "No");

    switch (action)
    {
        case false:
            return;
    }
}
```

Now when this validation code runs, the date times are ALWAYS different. the difference comes down to the ticks. The date, hours, minutes, seconds match but the ticks differ by very small amounts.

I suspect what is happening is that when I get the value of `StartDateTime` for `_uneditedEvent` it returns `DateTime.Now` again which is further ahead in terms of ticks.

Is there anyway I can set my second variable equal to the exact properties of the first variables (a reference).

I've done a similar thing in Objective-C which has the concept of mutable & unmutable. Although this is probably not correct syntax I could do something like `StartDateTime = [_eventStartDate Copy]` which would give me a clone of that variable.

Any ideas on how I can get this to work, for now I've had to disable date validation.

Comment: We would need to see the code creating your _eventItem

Comment: If you have 2 different assignations of `DateTime.Now` then you will have time difference. In this case you might want to consider comparing time up to seconds and not until ticks.

Comment: @AsheraH nothing to see, a new `EventItem` gets initialised just above the lines I showed on here. I call these 2 lines when creating `_eventItem = new EventItem();` & `_uneditedEvent = new EventItem();`. The variables have the same `DateTime` up to seconds, its just ticks that vary.

Comment: @EzLo Yes thats my fundamental problem, I wanted to know if I could just copy the first assignation to the second variable. I had thought about comparing seconds, but I worried that on fringe cases the seconds wouldn't match, that bug would never get sorted!

Comment: Exactly what variables or values are you assigning in `_eventItem = new EventItem();` ? Because if they are not the same ones you use in  `_uneditedEvent = new EventItem()
{
    StartDateTime = _eventStartDate,
    EndDateTime = _eventEndDate,
};` of course they will be different. (basically, if you are calling `DateTime.Now` again ...)

Comment: @AsheraH I'm assigning nothing, the init method will get called when adding an `EventItem` in the app. The `_eventItem` and `_uneditedEventItem` are both blank objects with nothing set when I run the above code. Since I need to set the value of Start/End Date on my `_eventItem` immediately (so it is reflected in my view), I need to copy this value to unedited event. You are right, I am assigning DateTime.Now twice and I simply want `_uneditedEvent` to be a carbon copy of `_eventItem`.